# std::vector inside a template class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I need to create a vector inside a template class as follow:

```
template <typename Float>
class Mat
{
public:
    std::vector<Float> P(2);
};
```

and in the main function :

```
int main()
{
  Mat<double> M;
  M.P[0] = 1;
}
```

However, during the compilation I get this error:

> C3867 'Mat::P': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member func.

Do you have any idea what is the problem?

Comment: You mean `std::vector<Float> P = std::vector<Float>(2);` ? Or just write Mat constructor, then you can use `Mat(): P(2) { }` syntax

Comment: std::vector<Float> P = std::vector<Float>(2); actually worked !!! I don't know ht since it is not needed outside a class !